# Drag and Drop items from a WPF application onto Desktop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a WPF application containing set of UserControls. Requirement is that a user should be able to drag any of these UC's from application and drop it anywhere on screen(outside the main application window).

From what I have learnt about D&D functionality in WPF , a drag source and drop target is must. But in the above case the drag and drop is across process and there is no predefined drop target.

Any idea , suggestion , approach etc are welcomed. And I hope I have explained the scenario quiet clearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To drag to desktop, the drag target should be a file,

try this:
http://codebrewery.blogspot.com/2010/06/drag-and-drop-files-from-wpf-listviews.html